# FF 3.5, firebug "breaks" sIFR3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sifr, flash-cs4

I have sIFR3 working nicely, but whenever I open Firebug in FF 3.5, any attempt to inspect the page breaks? sIFR3. The page reverts to it's non-sIFR3 text. Not sure what I'm missing.

Updated*

You'll notice the same behavior on one of the sample sites listed on the sIFR3 wiki:
http://www.lightweb.pl/

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Firebug has unresolved issues on Firefox 3.5. I've been seeing a lot of people complain about it breaking on FF3.5, and I've seen about four new Firebug versions in the last few days.

Comment: True, but the official sIFR3 demo(http://dev.novemberborn.net/sifr3/beta2/demo/) works perfectly. It retains itself when inspecting with Firebug in same browser. Also, I'm using Flash CS4 to generate the font. Not sure if that makes a diff. Thx.

Comment: We'll need to see an example, then. Can't fix what doesn't happen in available demos...

Comment: hmm... I noticed this happens too when i visit one of the sample sites on the sIFR3 homepage. http://www.lightweb.pl/

Open Firebug and either click the inspect button, or open up the DOM tree and target an element. The sIFR text disappears and the browser text shows.